# Read from Mysql as Stream

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

when i read from `MySql` database,

```
    Map<String,String> jdbcOptions = new HashMap<String,String>();
                jdbcOptions.put("url", "url_");
                jdbcOptions.put("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                jdbcOptions.put("dbtable", "tab");
                jdbcOptions.put("user", "root");
                jdbcOptions.put("password", "1234");
  Dataset<Row> ds =   sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").options(jdbcOptions).load();
```

I'm looking for how to read and put the record lines in a `Stream`

Thank you for providing an example.

Comment: do you mean java stream? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

Comment: also please describe what kind of problem you trying to solve.

Comment: Exactly Java Stream like Stream<Row> st instead Dataset<Row> ds

Comment: and why do you need `Stream<Row>`. I am asking, because such conversion doesn't look like proper usage of Spark API.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can write something like this:

```
    Dataset<Row> ds = //...;
    Stream<Row> stream = Arrays.stream(ds.collect());
```

But please note, that `collect()` is an **action**, so this will trigger execution, and it will fetch all results from this table at and will send all information to the driver where it will be stored in memory as an array of `Row`, which can lead to out of memory error if a table is too big to fit in memory.
Also, note that it can be not the most performant way to fetch data from DB.

Comment: It's not working, The method stream(T[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (Object)